# Vim-Airline + screen bug

Tags: vim, vim-airline

Sometimes, when switching between windows in `screen`, my vim gets messed up and e.g. my actual and shown cursor position don't match up (by 1 line), which is infuriating. I tinkered around a bit and its probably because of `vim-airline` being too long for the terminal. You can see the reason for my suspicion in the following image. Notice the orange rectangles in the lines below the `airline`. FYI, here is my minimized [vimrc](https://pastebin.com/ZAwZWjcE).

Switching tabs fixes the bug temporarily, but it's not a long-term solution.

I'd appreciate any help.

[image: vim-airline bug]

Comment: Would you consider switching to `tmux` a viable solution if this is specific to `screen`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my server and `tmux` isn't available, so I'd really like to solve this in `screen`.